# Как получить дату в другом формате(android)

Tags: android

не знаю как преобразовать время и дату в нужный формат. Я получаю текстовую строку с датой и временем, но мне нужно получить ее в другом формате, как правильно это реализовать?

Код функций:

```
// установка начальных даты и времени
private void setInitialDateTime() {

    currentDateTime.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity(),
            dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
}

// установка обработчика выбора времени
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};

// установка обработчика выбора даты
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};
```

Нужен вот такой формат:

> 2018-08-17T12:00:00.000Z

Comment: Вам нужно дату в текст преобразовать? Можно через `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")` В Вашем случае, как я понял  `currentDateTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").format(new Date(dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis()));`

Comment: @Chubatiy, Спасибо большое, это помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Для этого предлагаю воспользоватся `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")`

В Вашем случае, как я понял, метод  `setInitialDateTime()` приобретет следующий вид:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

// установка начальных даты и времени
private void setInitialDateTime() {
    currentDateTime.setText(SDF.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
}
```